# Custom Restangular GET method

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm making a GET request to my web api, the url goes like `/users/exist/:username`

I've created the custom method that works:

```
RestangularProvider.addElementTransformer('users', true, function(user) {

    user.addRestangularMethod('exist', 'get', 'exist');
    return user;
});
```

But I don't know how to add the `:username` in the url.

Is it even possible?