# Restangular sending OPTIONS method before GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, restangular

I'm working with an API that only accepts the GET method and restricts the use of the OPTIONS. When I send requests in chrome (bypassing cors via `--disable-web-security`) it sends the OPTIONS method right before the GET method preventing the resources from being obtained.

In Safari, however, I can obtain the resource as it only sends a GET. Im testing on mobile through the ionic framework and I cannot get it get the resources, Im assuming the OPTIONS is what's causing this. I've tried creating a custom request and though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738289/restangular-how-do-i-reach-this-api-using-get-method), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200404/sending-get-parameters-in-restangular) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426020/custom-restangular-get-method) and the docs would help but I haven't been having any luck. This is what my code looks like, I just started using Restangular and still figuring it out and any help/tips is appreciated. Thanks.

```
      .constant('baseURL', {
          url: 'https://api.example.com'
      })

      .config([
  'RestangularProvider', 'baseURL',
  function(RestangularProvider, baseURL) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(baseURL.url);


    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + baseURL.jwt
    })

  }
])


      .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular',
          function($scope, Restangular) {

              Restangular.one('destinations').get('').then(function(destinations) {

      $scope.destinationBase = destinations;

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I hadn't ever worked with preflight issues and thats what this was. I just opened my browser set to disable cors

Answer (score 0):

You could try intercepting the response and, if the method was `OPTIONS` and the request was made to the URL in question, modify the response code to `200` or `204`.

Just a matter of preference here, but rather than using [RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor), I would add a function to the [$httpProvider.interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) array. Restangular uses `$http` under the hood, so why not skip the middle man and go straight to the source?

Something like this should work:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['restangular'])
    .config(httpConfig);

function httpConfig($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.unshift(interceptor);

    function interceptor() {
        return {
            response: responseInterceptor
        };

        function responseInterceptor(response) {
            if (response.config.url === 'http://my.api.com/endpoint' && response.config.method === 'OPTIONS' && response.status > 299) {
                response.status = 204;
                response.statusText = 'No Content';
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

The `response` object is described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage), and `response.config` is described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

Comment: Thanks but Im working on the clientside and have no access to the serverside

Comment: $http is an Angular service, the code I gave you intercepts the response on the client side.

Comment: I just noticed that, Im going to see what this can do, I did know I could do this!

Comment: it seems as though by adding a "RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders" causes it to spit out OPTIONS before a GET so I made another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171342/how-can-i-chain-in-restangulars-setdefaultrequestparams

Comment: @qizzacious I'm not sure if I answered this question for you. Were you asking how to overcome a rejected pre-flight OPTIONS request? Consider revising the question title and, if my answer is correct for this question, please accept.  I'll take a look at your other question and try to help.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a preflight issue. I didn't open my browser correctly disabling it. Thanks for you time.